# jQuery Submit Handler Ajax Need Double Click to Execute

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I want to ask you about jQuery Submit Handler Ajax.

In my case, I need double click button to execute. Why? And how can I set just 1 click button and then execute.

And here is my code so far :

```
$(window).load(function()
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
$('#forms2').validate(
            {
rules
}
submitHandler: function(form)
                {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                            var form = $('#forms2'); // contact form
                            var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button
                            var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

                            // form submit event
                            form.on('submit', function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
                                // sending ajax request through jQuery
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'post_prod_rev.php', // form action url
                                    type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
                                    dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
                                    data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
                                    beforeSend: function() {
                                        alert.fadeOut();
                                        submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
                                    },
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                                        form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                                        submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
                                    },
                                    error: function(e) {
                                        console.log(e)
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made it as complicated as possible, there is no need to use `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` together and in the `submitHandler` there is no need to use `$(document).ready()` again

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#forms2').validate({
        rules: {},
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var form = $('#forms2'); // contact form
            var submit = $('#submit'); // submit button
            var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

            $.ajax({
                url: 'post_prod_rev.php', // form action url
                type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
                dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
                data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
                beforeSend: function () {
                    alert.fadeOut();
                    submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                    form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                    submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. 1 question, how can I hide message notification from post_prod_rev.php if I try to click the button (The condition after I submit 1 data and message notification appear).